# Cannot find module child-process

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

"child-process" should be a built in node library.  However, when I type "require('child-process') in the node shell, I get the error: "Cannot find module 'child-process'".  Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `require('child_process');` (with underscore, not hyphen).

Comment: That did it!  Strange that most examples online use a dash, not an underscore.  I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me.  Thanks!

Comment: And there are definitely a lot of examples that use a hyphen on the internet. :-/